# Why do we have lower and upper bounds for datatypes in MPI?

Tags: mpi

Or the question can be paraphrased like this:
*Why may one need a datatype with a non-zero lower bound?*

Consider the following example:

```
struct S {
  int a;
  int b;
  float c;
  float d;
} array[N];
```

If I had an array of type `S[]` and I wanted to send only values of fields `b` and
`d`, I would create a `datatype` with the type map `{ (4, MPI_INT), (12, MPI_FLOAT) }`.
At first, it seems that such a type could be used to correctly send an array of
`struct S`:

```
MPI_Send(array, N, datatype, ...);
```

But this doesn't work if `N > 1`.
Such a type would have `lb = 4`, `ub = 16` and `extent = ub - lb = 12`. That is,
MPI would consider that the second element of the array starts 12 bytes from the
first one, which is not true.

Well, that may be not a big deal. After all, generally, for such partially sent structures
we *have* to specify the exact size of the structure:

```
MPI_Type_create_resized(datatype, 0, sizeof(struct S), &resized);
```

But I wonder why we always need to specify a zero lower bound. Why would
someone need a non-zero lower bound? The datatypes with non-zero lower bounds looks extremely confusing to me, and I cannot make any sense of them.

If I were to design a type system for MPI, I would describe a type with a single
parameter - its size (extent), which is the stride between two adjacent elements of an array. In terms of MPI, I would always set `lb = 0` and `extent = ub`. Such a system looks much clearer to me, and it would work correctly in the example described above.

But MPI has chosen the different way. We have two *independent* parameters instead: the lower
and the upper bounds. Why is it so? What's the use of this additional flexibility? When should one use datatypes with a non-zero lower bound?

Answer (score 0):

You have no idea what kind of weird and complex structures one finds in scientific and engineering codes. [The standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) is designed to be as general as possible and to provide maximum flexibility. Section 4.1.6 *Lower-Bound and Upper-Bound Markers* begins like this:

> It is often convenient to define explicitly the lower bound and upper bound of a type map, and override the definition given on page 105. This allows one to define a datatype that has "holes" at its beginning or its end, or a datatype with entries that extend above the upper bound or below the lower bound. Examples of such usage are provided in Section 4.1.14.
>   Also, the user may want to overide *[sic]* the alignment rules that are  used to compute upper bounds and extents. E.g., a C compiler may allow the user to overide *[sic]* default alignment rules for some of the structures within a program. The user has to specify explicitly the bounds of the datatypes that match these structures.

The simplest example of a datatype with non-zero lower bound is a structure with absolute addresses used as offsets, useful in, e.g., sending structures with pointers to data scattered in memory. Such a datatype is used with `MPI_BOTTOM` specified as the buffer address, which corresponds to the bottom of the memory space (`0` on most systems). If the lower bound would be fixed to `0`, then you have to find the data item with the lowest address fist and compute all offsets relative to it.

Another example is the use of `MPI_Type_create_subarray` to create a datatype that describes a subarray of an n-dimensional array. With zero lower bounds you will have to provide a pointer to the beginning of the subarray. With non-zero lower bounds you just give a pointer to the beginning of the whole array instead. And you can also create a contiguous datatype of such subarray datatypes in order to send such n-dimensional "slices" from an n+1-dimensional array.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't actually explain anything. 1) I searched through the standard and found a handful of examples with MPI_Type_create_resized. None of the examples used non-zero lb, though. 2) I didn't get your point about the MPI_BOTTOM part. The structure you described is inherently one of a kind. You will never have an array of such structures. So, only type map matters for such a datatype, while the bounds don't matter at all. 3) MPI_Type_create_subarray creates a datatype with lb = 0.

Comment: 1) The examples provided in the standard are not exhaustive. A legitimate use for types with negative LB is for handling Fortran arrays with negative indices, e.g. `INTEGER A(-5:5)`. 2) The LB of a type is just the minimum offset in the typemap unless an explicit LB marker was placed using `MPI_Type_create_resized`. MPI is not used to only send arrays. 3) This true LB of datatypes created with `MPI_Type_create_subarray` when the subarray doesn't start at the beginning of the array is non-zero. It places explicit bound markers, just as you do in your example.

Comment: You do not *have* to use `0` as LB in the call to `MPI_Type_create_resized`. It is perfectly valid to do: `MPI_Type_get_extent(datatype, &lb, &extent); MPI_Type_create_resized(datatype, lb, sizeof(struct S), &resized);` and `resized` will have a non-zero LB and will still be usable for sending arrays of `struct S`. LB of `0` is used for convenience because it simplifies computing the offsets in most cases when further combining the datatypes. That's what the subarray constructor does and that's why the datatypes have their LB explicitly set to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the only reason to have both LB and UB markers is it simplifies the description of datatype construction.  The MPI datatypes are described by a type map (list of offsets and types, including possible LB/UB markers) and all the datatype construction calls define the new typemap in terms of the old typemap.

When you have LB/UB markers in the old typemap and you follow the rules of construction of the new typemap from the old, you get a natural definition of the LB/UB marker in the new type which defines the extent of the new type.  If extent were a separate property on the side of the typemap, you'd have to define what the new extent is for every datatype construction call.

Other than that I fundamentally I agree with you on the meaninglessness of having LB/UB as two separate pieces of data, when the only thing they're used for is to define the extent.  Once you add LB/UB markers, their meaning is completely disconnected from any notion of actual data offsets.

If you wanted to put an int at displacement 4 and have its extent be 8, it would be fine to construct

```
[(LB,4), (int,4), (UB,12)]
```

but it would be equally fine to construct any of

```
[(LB,0),(int,4),(UB,8)]
[(LB,1000000),(int,4),(UB,1000008)]
[(LB,-1000),(int,4),(UB,-992)]
```

The above are all completely equivalent in behavior because they have the same extent.

When explanations of LB/UB markers talk about how you need to have datatypes where the first data displacement is non-0, I think that's misleading.  It's true you need to be able to make types like that, but the LB/UB markers aren't fundamentally connected to the data displacements.  I'm concerned that suggesting they are connected will lead an MPI user to write invalid code if they think the LB is intrinsically related to the data offsets.